# Complex differential operators

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-operators

Consider the differential operators

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z} }$ defined by

$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}  = \frac {1}{2} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \frac{i \partial}{\partial y}$) ; $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z} } = \frac {1}{2} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} +\frac{i \partial}{\partial y}$).

**Prove that if $f$ is holomorphic then $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z} } = 0$**.

I start like that Proof: let $f$ be a holomorphic function such that $f = u + iv$ meaning $f(x,y) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ so that means $f$ has a first partial derivatives that satisfy the cauchy riemann equations.

So i am thinking something like that

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}  = (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{i \partial v}{\partial x}$) ; $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y } = (\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} +\frac{i \partial v}{\partial y}$)

and the cauchy rieman equation is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} =- \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

Now i really do not know how to go about this problem, i kept asking what exactly am i looking for here. Help anyone.

Comment: i find a way to use the operator on the function $f$ on  $\frac{\partial }{\partial z} and \frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{z}}$ After making the substitution i will have  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{i}{2} (\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$) and for  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} -  \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{i}{2}( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$)

Comment: But i still do not know what i am looking for

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Cauchy and Riemann deserve a capital letter

Answer (score 3):

The fact is indeed a consequence of the CR equations.  Note that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=\frac12 \frac{\partial (u+iv)}{\partial x}+\frac12 \frac{\partial (iu-v)}{\partial y}=\frac12 \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)+i\,\frac12 \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)=0$$

since the last terms in parantheses are zero by the CR equations and $f$ is analytic by assumption.  The result implies that no analytic function can have dependence on $\bar z$ (i.e., cannot be a function of $\bar z$.

Comment: Thank you i see it now thank you finally i can move on after 4 hours man thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.